# XMLHttpRequest cross domain

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, response

i have this javascript code for extract text from page, it works fine if i open file in my domain, but i cant get text from file in another domain, because some security reasons. So my question is how can i please extract text from another website in javascript, please without jquery.

Thank you

```
function reqListener () {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onload = reqListener;

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://anotherweb.com/datafile.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
xhr.send(null);
```

I tried this and it doesnt work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/index.php",
      dataType : "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
      },
      error: function (e) {                
      }
      });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cross-origin requests simply [aren't allowed by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). The remote server may provide permission to your application through [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) or by supporting Ajax alternatives like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). But, if `datafile.php` doesn't offer any of those, then you'll need to create your own server-side layer to mediate the request between the browser and `anotherweb.com`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  header is set in response headers of `datafile.php` it works :)

Comment: yes thank you, but i dont have access to datafile.php :/

Comment: This it's impossible :( The cross domain target file(server) should allow requests from your domain.

Comment: it musts something exists that allow to display text from external page

Comment: You cannot do a cross domain get of text/html in any modern browser.

The only return type that I know of that works currently is jsonp

Comment: oh okey, can you send me please any easy tutorial for getting text/html from external page? Thank you very much

Comment: @tomsk Does this answer your question?

Comment: This is what I added and works great: header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

Answer (score 2):

you can send the request back to your server, then redirect it to wherever you want:

javascript function:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}}
xmlhttp.open("POST","response.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

.htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^response(.*?)\.php http://example.com/query [R]
```

The javascript function will write the response from example.com in the txtHint div.

I wrote it like this because this is how I use it in my app so I only did minor changes.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) to get around the cross domain restrictions.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do cross domain request,e.g. from example1.com to example2.com through XMLHttpRequest or jQuery(which is a wrapper of XMLHttpRequest) due to security issue in client side(browser). This can be effectively implemented in modern browser supporting HTML5 through CORS(cross origin resource sharing, which cannot be available in every client browser.
So, the solution is to insert script tag in example1.com of example2.com, and this solution is known as JSON-P(JSON with padding), the name could be misleading as the data can be in any format served by the server(example2.com). Its implementation code is given in this link http://newtechinfo.net/jsonp-for-cross-domain-ajax/